# Couchbase subquery on WHERE clause

Tags: sql, subquery, couchbase

So I am trying to run a query on my db that will grab the username's info based on a username and password but both are on the same table. When I run the code:

```
SELECT subscriberRef
FROM csp
WHERE username = "ville" AND pass = "ppp"
```

I get the correct reference which is "S:1" but when I subquery it in a WHERE clause like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM csp 
WHERE META(csp).id = (SELECT subscriberRef 
                     FROM csp as csp1
                     WHERE username = "ville" AND pass = "ppp")
```

It returns []. 
WHY?????????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are getting the result from the first query you get an array of JSONs, which cannot be equivalent to a simple String.

for example for that query

```
SELECT  subscriberRef 
FROM webinar as w
WHERE username = "ppp" AND `password` = "vvv"
```

you will get that result:

```
[
  {
    "subscriberRef": "person::1"
  }
]
```

the best way I can think of to solve it is to use the raw keyword, to get a simple JSON array of the values only.

```
SELECT  raw subscriberRef 
FROM webinar as w
WHERE username = "ppp" AND `password` = "vvv"
```

result:

```
[
  "person::1"
]
```

and from here you can build you query:

```
select *
from myBucket
where meta().id in (
SELECT raw subscriberRef 
FROM myBucket as w
WHERE username = "ppp" AND `password` = "vvv")
```

now I won't use "=" but "in" because this is an array of data (having 1 value)

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because the result of the the subquery isn't a string, but it's an object with one field. E.g. "foo" is not the same as { "bar" : "foo"}.

I don't know if there's a way around that (there probably is), but have you considered using a JOIN to go in the other direction instead? Something like:

```
SELECT csp.*
FROM `default` csp1
JOIN `default` csp ON KEYS csp1.subscriberRef
WHERE csp1.username = "ville" and csp1.pass = "ppp"
```

Comment: this what I ended up doing but i did not want to join the database with itself for such a simple query. Couchbase provides an unnest clause, will look into that.